# Service Broker tutorial -- two SQL Server instances on one machine. How to route?

Tags: service-broker

I am following the [Completing a Conversation Between Instances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839483%28v=sql.105%29) tutorial from MSDN. The [Lesson 2: Creating the Initiator Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839497%28v=sql.105%29) (at the end) shows, how to create routes at the initiator site (shortened):

```
...
USE InstInitiatorDB;
CREATE ROUTE InstTargetRoute
WITH SERVICE_NAME =
       N'//TgtDB/2InstSample/TargetService',
     ADDRESS = N'TCP://MyTargetComputer:4022';

...

USE msdb;
CREATE ROUTE InstInitiatorRoute
WITH SERVICE_NAME =
       N'//InstDB/2InstSample/InitiatorService',
     ADDRESS = N'LOCAL'
```

and the [Lesson 3: Completing the Target Conversation Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb839486%28v=sql.105%29) does the same on the target instance:

```
USE InstTargetDB;
CREATE ROUTE InstInitiatorRoute
WITH SERVICE_NAME =
       N'//InstDB/2InstSample/InitiatorService',
     ADDRESS = N'TCP://MyInitiatorComputer:4022';

...

USE msdb
CREATE ROUTE InstTargetRoute
WITH SERVICE_NAME =
        N'//TgtDB/2InstSample/TargetService',
     ADDRESS = N'LOCAL';
```

However, the tutorial assumes that the SQL server instances run on separate hardware. How should I change the routing or whatever if the two SQL server instances run on the same machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two instances cannot share the listener port. On Lesson 1 you had this:

```
...
CREATE ENDPOINT InstTargetEndpoint
STATE = STARTED
AS TCP ( LISTENER_PORT = 4022 )
...
```

and on Lesson 2 you had this:

```
...
CREATE ENDPOINT InstInitiatorEndpoint
STATE = STARTED
AS TCP ( LISTENER_PORT = 4022 )
...
```

This will not work as both instances are configured to listen on the same TCP port. One has to be different. Lets make the target listen on 4023:

```
...
CREATE ENDPOINT InstTargetEndpoint
STATE = STARTED
AS TCP ( LISTENER_PORT = 4023 )
...
```

Then the route from the initiator to the target has to specify port 4023 now:

```
...
CREATE ROUTE InstTargetRoute
WITH SERVICE_NAME =
       N''//TgtDB/2InstSample/TargetService'',
     ADDRESS = N''TCP://MyTargetComputer:4023'';';
...
```

Everything else stays the same.

Comment: If I understand it well, the `4022` is the usual port number for the purpose. Are there any recommendations what a different port should be used? I have seen somewhere also `5022`. I understand that the 4022 is actually by convention, and one could use almost whatever free port. But what is *a good behaviour*?

Comment: Is there a reason msdb is employed in the example? Is that what production environment should use?

Comment: @milez please ask a separate question.

Comment: @RemusRusanu I asked here http://stackoverflow.com/q/38472867/5110359 :)